# Issue with WebDriver: Cannot Connect to Chrome at 127.0.0.1:46165 - Chrome Not Reachable

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am encountering an issue when trying to use `Selenium WebDriver` with Chrome. The error message I receive is:

`selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot connect to chrome at 127.0.0.1:46165 from chrome not reachable.`

This issue occurs when I try to initiate the WebDriver.
Here is my code:

```
import undetected_chromedriver as uc
import time

options = uc.ChromeOptions()
profile = "/home/richard/.config/google-chrome/Default"
options.add_argument("--user-data-dir=/home/richard/.config/google-chrome/")
options.add_argument("--profile-directory=Profile 1")
driver = uc.Chrome(options=options, use_subprocess=True) 
driver.get("https://www.google.com")
time.sleep(10000)
```

Whenever I run the code, it just open the profile and mention the error but not go to `google.com`

Could you please help me, thanks so much